# AngularJS query resource once and use data throughout app

Tags: angularjs

My App has several views,each view has a controller.

I have several API resources returning standard JSON arrays.Whenever a view changes,the resources are re-queried for new data which is fairly slow.  I'd prefer to provide my controllers with the API resources without requerying each time.

Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: IMO, using service (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services) is the standard way to share resource among controllers.  It basically is a singleton that is injectable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly then this is what services are for. They're kind of like a central place for controllers share data.

I looked over the jsfiddle for the code used in this tutorial:

http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-communicating-between-controllers/

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
myModule.factory('mySharedService', function($rootScope) {
    var sharedService = {};

    sharedService.message = '';

    sharedService.prepForBroadcast = function(msg) {
        this.message = msg;
        this.broadcastItem();
    };

    sharedService.broadcastItem = function() {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
    };

    return sharedService;
});

function ControllerZero($scope, sharedService) {
    $scope.handleClick = function(msg) {
        sharedService.prepForBroadcast(msg);
    };

    $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
        $scope.message = sharedService.message;
    });        
}

function ControllerOne($scope, sharedService) {
    $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
        $scope.message = 'ONE: ' + sharedService.message;
    });        
}

function ControllerTwo($scope, sharedService) {
    $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
        $scope.message = 'TWO: ' + sharedService.message;
    });
}

ControllerZero.$inject = ['$scope', 'mySharedService'];        

ControllerOne.$inject = ['$scope', 'mySharedService'];

ControllerTwo.$inject = ['$scope', 'mySharedService'];​
```

---

**EDIT**

For resource calls, I have a service right now that uses them like this. Sorry that its in coffeescript

```
.factory('EventService', (SubEvent, User) ->
    subevents = {}

    return {
        getSubevent: (subevent_id) ->
            SubEvent.get {subevent_id: subevent_id}, (subevent) ->

                participants = (participant.user for participant in subevent.participants)
                User.query {participants: participants}, (users) ->
                    for user,i in users
                        subevent.participants[i].user = user

                    subevents[subevent_id] = subevent
    }
)
```

Comment: This almost works but is there anyway to query the resources inside the service?  I seem to just get empty arrays if I try to manipulate them - even if I use a callback inside the query().

Comment: I'll mark as answered anyway, it's easiest enough to work around that for now though.  Thanks for the video too, that clears some stuff up.

Comment: I put up some code I'm using that uses resources within the service

Answer (score 0):

1. Place your shared resource into a service (this is almost always how you share data between controllers).
2. Cache the results within the service so the expensive query need only be performed once.

Since both [`$http`](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.%24http) and [`$resource`](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ngResource.%24resource) support caching out of the box, you don't need to write your own caching. To tweak the default caching behavior, check out [`$cacheFactory`](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.%24cacheFactory).

Here's an example from an application I'm working on:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);

app
  .factory('Worklogs', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/tempo/worklogs', {}, {
      'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true, cache: true}
    });
  })
  .controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, Worklogs, $log, $filter){
    $scope.search = SearchParameters;
    $scope.worklogs = Worklogs.query({dateFrom: $scope.search.dateFrom, dateTo: $scope.search.dateTo});
  })
  .controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, Worklogs, $log, $filter){
    $scope.search = SearchParameters;
    $scope.worklogs = Worklogs.query({dateFrom: $scope.search.dateFrom, dateTo: $scope.search.dateTo});
  })
```

The first time a controller loads and each time new parameters are passed into `query()`, the Worklogs service makes an HTTP request. Whenever a controller is changed and a previous query is repeated, Worklogs are loaded from the cache (and no HTTP request is made).

I'm using AngularJS 1.1.5 since the 1.0.x branch is missing loads of cool stuff...probably including this.